# One boxplot with Jitter and one without in the same viz

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, jitter

I would like to have a viz with one two boxplots, but only one of them have jittered data points.  I can create the viz below, but want the 'non-jit" to not have the datapoints.  Thanks for the help!

```
Amount = c(runif(20,1,100),5,25,50,75,90,(runif(20,1,100)),5,25,50,75,90)
Level = c(rep(1,25),rep(2,25))
Description = c(rep("jit",20),rep("non-jit",5),rep("jit",20),rep("non-jit",5))

Jitter = data.frame(Level,Description,Amount)
names(Jitter) = c("Level", "Description", "Amount")
View(Jitter)

Jitter$Description = factor(Jitter$Description, levels = c("jit", "non-jit"))
Jitter$Level = factor(Jitter$Level, levels = c("1", "2"))

ggplot(Jitter, aes(x=Amount, y = Description))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  geom_point(position = position_jitter())+
  facet_grid(Level~.)
```

[boxplots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sF9BR.png)

Comment: Fantastic!  Great solution - thank you boucyball!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you, we can just add tweak the data that is passed to `geom_point`. By default, `geom_point` inherits the `aes` as you've definied it in `ggplot`. By filtering the data, we just pass the points we wanted plotted

```
ggplot(Jitter, aes(x=Amount, y = Description))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  geom_point(data = Jitter %>% filter(Description != "non-jit"), 
             position = position_jitter())+
  facet_grid(Level~.)
```

[image]